# Timestamp as On Off in plot using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

I have one Excel which is having 10sec frequent data with timestamp ,In that I want where ever 10Sec frequency data is there it should show as On(1) and where frequency timestamp is not matched there it should show as OFF(0) as in Plot.

Sample Data:

```
timestamp
1/6/2017 0:00:10
1/6/2017 0:00:20
1/6/2017 0:00:40
1/6/2017 0:00:50
1/6/2017 0:01:00
```

So,

```
timestamp
    1/6/2017 0:00:39 timestamp is there ON
    1/6/2017 0:00:49 timestamp is not there Off
    1/6/2017 0:00:59 timestamp is there ON
    1/6/2017 0:01:09 timestamp is not there Off
    1/6/2017 0:01:19 timestamp is there ON
    1/6/2017 0:01:29 timestamp is there ON
    1/6/2017 0:01:39 timestamp is there ON
```

Code:Below is my code;in this I want to plot a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
#reading CSv
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
print (df)


#set Index
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
print (df)


#reindexing   
df.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='30s'))
```

This On Off should come in plot like On means up and Off means Down.

Thanks in advance.I am new in that Please help.

Comment: At which point do you need help? Where is the problem? What have you tried yet? Please see [ask] and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: sorry for writing question in wrong manner. Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. The main point here is that there is only one column in the DataFrame and if you set this column as index `df.set_index('timestamp')`, there is not data left to show. So you would first create another column with "on" values (or `1`s) and then reindex the dataframe. Using `fill_values` allows you to set the newly created dates to `0`. 
Finally just `plot` the data.

```
u = u"""timestamp
1/6/2017 0:00:10
1/6/2017 0:00:20
1/6/2017 0:00:40
1/6/2017 0:00:50
1/6/2017 0:01:00
1/6/2017 0:01:30
"""

import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

#reading CSv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), parse_dates=['timestamp'])
# create new column of `1`s
df["On"] = [1]*len(df)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='10s'), 
                fill_value=0)

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: its showing error like;ValueError: 'timestamp' is not in list

Comment: Its working ,minor mistake.Can we export this plot ?? to show properly which time is there it will show as up and missing will show as down?

Comment: The plot already shows times which were initially there being up and those missing down, right? To export the plot you can use `plt.savefig`.

Comment: while saving the fig its show blank.I want to save desired location.

Comment: if i want to give freq less than 1 min how we can give?

Comment: axis label i want to see my timestamp value? how we can show?